# Doctrine, When i create element i need to use the value of id in other field of the same table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this class :

```
Article (id, code)
```

When i create my article i need to add the id in the field code. Exemple in my database i need to have :

```
(id, code)

1, ARTICLE_1

2, ARTICLE_2
```

In fact the field code is equal to `ARTICLE + ID`, I try to complete this field with :

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->code = "ARTICLE_" . $this->getId();

}
```

but when i add my article, the Id is not generated and the function `getId` return nothing. I try to test `postPersist()` function but it's not a success.

Is there a good practice for this ?

Thanks

Djoo

Comment: If the code can be generated from the id anyways, why have the code in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks

I add the annotation  @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks to my Entity, and i had a function :

```
/** @ORM\PostPersist */
public function doStuffOnPostPersist()
{
    $this->setCode('ARTICLE_' . $this->getId());

}
```

With this solution, i have the id because i have already persist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can't use the "+" operator to concatenate a string with a variable but the "." symbol.

Try this instead:

`$this->code = "ARTICLE_" . $this->getId();`

Comment: I don't think this is the main issue here. At the time he persist his new entity, no id exists and therefore a correct concatenation will not solve it.

Comment: Sorry, it's an error of me when i wrote the question.
I have a "." in my code but the $this->getId() return nothing at the creation of the object because the object is not yet created.

Comment: my bad, you're right i read it to fast. Also as devsheeep said you can't get the id of an entity before you flush it for the first time (at least if your id is auto-generated)